# La aplicación de chat no se conecta al contenedor Docker de OpenSearch (localhost:9200) a pesar de que los contenedores funcionan correctamente

Tags: docker-compose, networking, opensearch, gradio

Estoy intentando conectar una aplicación gradio a mi contenedor opensearch pero me sigue diciendo que hay un problema de conexión cuando escribo algo en la interfaz web:

```
(.venv) computer@computer-GE66-Raider-11UH:~/dev/hello/chatbot-rag$ gradio gradio-chatbot.py 

Warning: Cannot statically find a gradio demo called demo. Reload work may fail.
Watching: '/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gradio', 
'/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag', '/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag'

/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/__init__.py:34: UserWarning: Importing PromptTemplate from langchain root module is no longer supported. Please use langchain.prompts.PromptTemplate instead.
  warnings.warn(
Initializing backend for chatbot
/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/__init__.py:698: FutureWarning: The `use_auth_token` argument is deprecated and will be removed in v5 of Transformers. Please use `token` instead.
  warnings.warn(
Loading checkpoint shards: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████| 2/2 [00:03<00:00,  1.67s/it]
Running on local URL:  http://0.0.0.0:7860

To create a public link, set `share=True` in `launch()`.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 203, in _new_conn
    sock = connection.create_connection(
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 85, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/opensearchpy/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 264, in perform_request
    response = self.pool.urlopen(
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 844, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 445, in increment
    raise reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/util.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 790, in urlopen
    response = self._make_request(
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 496, in _make_request
    conn.request(
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 395, in request
    self.endheaders()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1278, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1038, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 976, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 243, in connect
    self.sock = self._new_conn()
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 218, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7ff2e45c0dc0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gradio/routes.py", line 569, in predict
    output = await route_utils.call_process_api(
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gradio/route_utils.py", line 232, in call_process_api
    output = await app.get_blocks().process_api(
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gradio/blocks.py", line 1522, in process_api
    result = await self.call_function(
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gradio/blocks.py", line 1144, in call_function
    prediction = await anyio.to_thread.run_sync(
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/anyio/to_thread.py", line 33, in run_sync
    return await get_asynclib().run_sync_in_worker_thread(
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 877, in run_sync_in_worker_thread
    return await future
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 807, in run
    result = context.run(func, *args)
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gradio/utils.py", line 673, in wrapper
    response = f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/gradio-chatbot.py", line 28, in user
    answer = answer_question(user_message)
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/gradio-chatbot.py", line 13, in answer_question
    return backend.answer_query(question, prompt_template=backend.prompt_template, top_k=chatbot_config['top_k'])
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/backend.py", line 120, in answer_query
    docs = self.db.similarity_search(query, raw_response=True, k=top_k)
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/vectorstores/opensearch_vector_search.py", line 516, in similarity_search
    docs_with_scores = self.similarity_search_with_score(query, k, **kwargs)
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/vectorstores/opensearch_vector_search.py", line 541, in similarity_search_with_score
    hits = self._raw_similarity_search_with_score(query=query, k=k, **kwargs)
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/vectorstores/opensearch_vector_search.py", line 667, in _raw_similarity_search_with_score
    response = self.client.search(index=index_name, body=search_query)
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/opensearchpy/client/utils.py", line 181, in _wrapped
    return func(*args, params=params, headers=headers, **kwargs)
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/opensearchpy/client/__init__.py", line 1742, in search
    return self.transport.perform_request(
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/opensearchpy/transport.py", line 446, in perform_request
    raise e
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/opensearchpy/transport.py", line 409, in perform_request
    status, headers_response, data = connection.perform_request(
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/opensearchpy/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 279, in perform_request
    raise ConnectionError("N/A", str(e), e)
opensearchpy.exceptions.ConnectionError: ConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7ff2e45c0dc0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused) caused by: NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7ff2e45c0dc0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 203, in _new_conn
    sock = connection.create_connection(
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 85, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/opensearchpy/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 264, in perform_request
    response = self.pool.urlopen(
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 844, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 445, in increment
    raise reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/util.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 790, in urlopen
    response = self._make_request(
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 496, in _make_request
    conn.request(
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 395, in request
    self.endheaders()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1278, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1038, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 976, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 243, in connect
    self.sock = self._new_conn()
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 218, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7ff2e4413e20>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gradio/routes.py", line 569, in predict
    output = await route_utils.call_process_api(
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gradio/route_utils.py", line 232, in call_process_api
    output = await app.get_blocks().process_api(
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gradio/blocks.py", line 1522, in process_api
    result = await self.call_function(
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gradio/blocks.py", line 1144, in call_function
    prediction = await anyio.to_thread.run_sync(
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/anyio/to_thread.py", line 33, in run_sync
    return await get_asynclib().run_sync_in_worker_thread(
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 877, in run_sync_in_worker_thread
    return await future
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 807, in run
    result = context.run(func, *args)
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gradio/utils.py", line 673, in wrapper
    response = f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/gradio-chatbot.py", line 28, in user
    answer = answer_question(user_message)
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/gradio-chatbot.py", line 13, in answer_question
    return backend.answer_query(question, prompt_template=backend.prompt_template, top_k=chatbot_config['top_k'])
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/backend.py", line 120, in answer_query
    docs = self.db.similarity_search(query, raw_response=True, k=top_k)
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/vectorstores/opensearch_vector_search.py", line 516, in similarity_search
    docs_with_scores = self.similarity_search_with_score(query, k, **kwargs)
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/vectorstores/opensearch_vector_search.py", line 541, in similarity_search_with_score
    hits = self._raw_similarity_search_with_score(query=query, k=k, **kwargs)
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/vectorstores/opensearch_vector_search.py", line 667, in _raw_similarity_search_with_score
    response = self.client.search(index=index_name, body=search_query)
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/opensearchpy/client/utils.py", line 181, in _wrapped
    return func(*args, params=params, headers=headers, **kwargs)
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/opensearchpy/client/__init__.py", line 1742, in search
    return self.transport.perform_request(
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/opensearchpy/transport.py", line 446, in perform_request
    raise e
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/opensearchpy/transport.py", line 409, in perform_request
    status, headers_response, data = connection.perform_request(
  File "/home/computer/dev/Hello/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/opensearchpy/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 279, in perform_request
    raise ConnectionError("N/A", str(e), e)
opensearchpy.exceptions.ConnectionError: ConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7ff2e4413e20>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused) caused by: NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7ff2e4413e20>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused)
```

Aqui esta la applicacion gradio: gradio-chatbot.py:

```
import os
import backend
import yaml
import gradio as gr

with open("config.yaml", "r") as f:
    chatbot_config = yaml.load(f, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
    vector_store_config = chatbot_config['vector_store']
    backend = backend.Backend(chatbot_config)
    backend.load_embeddings_and_llm_models()

def answer_question(question):
    return backend.answer_query(question, prompt_template=backend.prompt_template, top_k=chatbot_config['top_k'])



with gr.Blocks(title='Chatbot') as demo:
    chatbot = gr.Chatbot()
    msg = gr.Textbox()
    clear = gr.Button("Clear")


    def user(user_message, history):
        answer = answer_question(user_message)
        return "", history + [[user_message, answer]]

    def bot(history):
        return history

    msg.submit(user, [msg, chatbot], [msg, chatbot], queue=False).then(
        bot, chatbot, chatbot
    )

    clear.click(lambda: None, None, chatbot, queue=False)

demo.launch(server_name="0.0.0.0")

Et voici le fichier de configuration:

version: 1.0

vector_store:
  opensearch_url: localhost:9200
  opensearch_user: elastic
  opensearch_password: changeme

watch_dir: /home/computer/Documents/Project_docs
index_pattern: test-ragg
embedding_model_name_or_path: intfloat/multilingual-e5-large
# llm_model_name_or_path: /home/computer/dev/text-generation-webui/models/models--meta-llama--Llama-2-7b-chat-hf/
llm_model_name_or_path: /home/computer/dev/Hello/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf
bulk_size: 10000
chunk_size: 500
chunk_overlap: 50
max_new_tokens: 512
max_num_tokens: 1024
temperature: 0.1
top_k: 1
prompt_template: >
  Answer the question based only on the following extracted parts of a long document:

  ======
  
  Extracted parts: 
  
  {context}
  
  ======
  
  question: {question} 
  
  Remove duplicated information and create a short answer. 
  
  Answer in the following language: french
```

Y su configuracion `config.yaml`:

```
version: 1.0

vector_store:
  opensearch_url: localhost:9200
  opensearch_user: elastic
  opensearch_password: changeme

watch_dir: /home/computer/Documents/GEDAI
index_pattern: test-ragg
embedding_model_name_or_path: intfloat/multilingual-e5-large
# llm_model_name_or_path: /home/computer/dev/text-generation-webui/models/models--meta-llama--Llama-2-7b-chat-hf/
llm_model_name_or_path: /home/computer/dev/Hello/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf
bulk_size: 10000
chunk_size: 500
chunk_overlap: 50
max_new_tokens: 512
max_num_tokens: 1024
temperature: 0.1
top_k: 1
prompt_template: >
  Answer the question based only on the following extracted parts of a long document:

  ======
  
  Extracted parts: 
  
  {context}
  
  ======
  
  question: {question} 
  
  Remove duplicated information and create a short answer. 
  
  Answer in the following language: french
```

Y aqui esta el docker-compose que inicia opensearch y opensarch dashboards:

```
version: '3'
services:

  # Serveur OpenSearch (fork Elasticsearch 7.10)
  opensearch:
    image: opensearchproject/opensearch:2.11.0
    container_name: opensearch
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - node.roles=ml, data, master, ingest
      - plugins.ml_commons.native_memory_threshold=100
      - plugins.security.disabled=true # ATTENTION : SECURITE DESACTIVE
      - "OPENSEARCH_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms4096m -Xmx4096m"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/opensearch/data:/usr/share/opensearch/data
    # command: bash -c "sudo mkdir -p /usr/share/opensearch/data/nodes && chown -R 1000:1000 /usr/share/opensearch/data"
    # command: bash -c "/bin/bash /usr/local/bin/start-opensearch.sh"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9600:9600
    networks:
      - opensearch-net
      
  # Opensearch dashboard pour la visualisation
  opensearch-dashboards:
    image: opensearchproject/opensearch-dashboards:2.11.0
    container_name: opensearch-dashboards
    ports:
        - 5601:5601
    networks:
      - opensearch-net
    environment:
      - 'OPENSEARCH_HOSTS=["http://opensearch:9200"]'
      - "DISABLE_SECURITY_DASHBOARDS_PLUGIN=true"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/opensearch-dashboards/config/opensearch_dashboards.yml:/usr/share/opensearch-dashboards/config/opensearch_dashboards.yml
    depends_on:
      - opensearch

networks:
  opensearch-net:
    driver: bridge
```

No sé si esta importante pero al principio tenia que crear archivos:

```
(.venv) computer@computer-GE66-Raider-11UH:~/dev/hello/chatbot-rag$ sudo mkdir -p /usr/share/opensearch/data/nodes
(.venv) computer@computer-GE66-Raider-11UH:~/dev/hello/chatbot-rag$ sudo chown -R 1000:1000 /usr/share/opensearch/data/nodes
```

A veces obtengo este error cuando hizo docker compose up mientras que créé este repertorio /nodes:

```
opensearch             | OpenSearchException[failed to bind service]; nested: AccessDeniedException[/usr/share/opensearch/data/nodes];
opensearch             | Likely root cause: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /usr/share/opensearch/data/nodes
opensearch             |        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:90)
opensearch             |        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:106)
opensearch             |        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
opensearch             |        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:397)
opensearch             |        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:700)
opensearch             |        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createAndCheckIsDirectory(Files.java:807)
opensearch             |        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Files.java:793)
opensearch             |        at org.opensearch.env.NodeEnvironment.lambda$new$0(NodeEnvironment.java:325)
opensearch             |        at org.opensearch.env.NodeEnvironment$NodeLock.<init>(NodeEnvironment.java:262)
opensearch             |        at org.opensearch.env.NodeEnvironment.<init>(NodeEnvironment.java:323)
opensearch             |        at org.opensearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:525)
opensearch             |        at org.opensearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:407)
opensearch             |        at org.opensearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:242)
opensearch             |        at org.opensearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:242)
opensearch             |        at org.opensearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:404)
opensearch             |        at org.opensearch.bootstrap.OpenSearch.init(OpenSearch.java:180)
opensearch             |        at org.opensearch.bootstrap.OpenSearch.execute(OpenSearch.java:171)
opensearch             |        at org.opensearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:104)
opensearch             |        at org.opensearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:138)
opensearch             |        at org.opensearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:101)
opensearch             |        at org.opensearch.bootstrap.OpenSearch.main(OpenSearch.java:137)
opensearch             |        at org.opensearch.bootstrap.OpenSearch.main(OpenSearch.java:103)
opensearch             | For complete error details, refer to the log at /usr/share/opensearch/logs/docker-cluster.log
```

Pero no parece que existen los logs:

```
(.venv) cert@cert-GE66-Raider-11UH:~/dev/hello/chatbot-rag$ cat /usr/share/opensearch/logs/docker-cluster.log
cat: /usr/share/opensearch/logs/docker-cluster.log: No such file or directory
```